# Memory Manager - Access Violation Writing Location Exception

Tags: c++, exception, pointers, memory-management

I have been doing a little research about Game Engine development, and I finaly begun trying to write a Memorymanager. I got the idea from the Game Engine Design Book from Eberly. In the constructor I allocate a memoryblock and add a header and footer to it which both have a size attribute and used. But now I get a Access Writing Voilation. I already heard something about pointers being const and only readable, but I have no idea how I can fix this.

Here's the MemoryManager.h file:

```
// MemoryManager.h - Header file //

#ifndef H_MemoryManager
#define H_MemoryManager

#include "IMemoryManager.h"

class HeaderBlock
{
public:
bool Used;
unsigned int Size;

HeaderBlock* Prev;
HeaderBlock* Next;
};

class FooterBlock
{
public:
bool Used;
unsigned int Size;
};

class MemoryManager : public IMemoryManager
{
private:
int m_MemoryBudget;
char* m_FullMemory;
HeaderBlock* m_FreeBlock;

int m_hsize;        // Size of the header
int m_fsize;        // Size of the footer
int m_hfsize;       // Size of the HeaderandFooter

public:
// Constructor and Destructor
MemoryManager(int Budget);
virtual ~MemoryManager();

// Functions
virtual char* Allocate(unsigned int RequestSize);
virtual char* Deallocate(char* pDeallocate);

HeaderBlock* SearchByPolicy(unsigned int RequestSize);
 };

#endif
```

Here's the Constructor implementation:

```
MemoryManager::MemoryManager(int Budget)
{
m_MemoryBudget = Budget;
m_FullMemory = (char*)malloc(m_MemoryBudget);

m_hsize = sizeof(HeaderBlock);
m_fsize = sizeof(FooterBlock);
m_hfsize = m_hsize + m_fsize;

HeaderBlock* header = (HeaderBlock*)m_FullMemory;
header->Used = false;
header->Size = m_MemoryBudget;

FooterBlock* footer = (FooterBlock*)(m_FullMemory + m_MemoryBudget - m_fsize);
footer->Used = false;
footer->Size = m_MemoryBudget;

header->Prev = header;
header->Next = header;

m_FreeBlock = (HeaderBlock*)m_FullMemory;
}
```

And here is the allocation method where I get the error at the error

```
usedHeader->Used = true;
usedFooter->Used = true;
freeHeader->Used = false; 
freeFooter->Used = false; // HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION
```

---

```
char* MemoryManager::Allocate(unsigned int RequestSize)
{

HeaderBlock* header = SearchByPolicy(RequestSize);


if(header == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

unsigned int Size = header->Size;
FooterBlock* footer = (FooterBlock*)((header + Size - m_fsize));

// 1.The size to be allocated fits EXACTLY in the Block pointed by header.
if(Size == RequestSize + m_hfsize)
{
    char* allocated = (char*)header + m_hsize;
    header->Used = true;
    footer->Used = true;

    if(header->Next == header)
    {
        // This is the only block on the free list
        m_FreeBlock = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        m_FreeBlock->Prev->Next = m_FreeBlock->Next;
        m_FreeBlock->Next->Prev = m_FreeBlock->Prev;
        m_FreeBlock = m_FreeBlock->Next;
    }
    return allocated;
}

// 2. The block has more storage than is needed for the allocation request.
if(Size >= RequestSize + 2*m_hfsize)
{
    char* allocated = (char*)(header + m_hsize);

    // Split the block in a "Used"-Block and a "Free"-Block
    HeaderBlock* usedHeader = header;
    FooterBlock* usedFooter = (FooterBlock*)(header + m_hsize + RequestSize);
    HeaderBlock* freeHeader = (HeaderBlock*)(usedFooter + m_fsize);
    FooterBlock* freeFooter = footer;

    usedHeader->Used = true;
    usedFooter->Used = true;
    freeHeader->Used = false;
    freeFooter->Used = false;

    unsigned int usedSize = RequestSize + m_hfsize;
    freeHeader->Size = header->Size - usedSize;
    usedHeader->Size = usedSize;

    freeHeader->Prev = header->Prev;
    freeHeader->Next = header->Next;

    m_FreeBlock = freeHeader;

    return allocated;
}

// 3. The block has more storage then the Request, but to less to divide into two     blocks.
char* allocated = (char*)header + m_hsize;
header->Used = true;
footer->Used = true;

//Detach from the free list;
if(header->Next == header)
{
    // This is the only block on the free list
    m_FreeBlock = 0;
}
else
{
    m_FreeBlock->Prev->Next = m_FreeBlock->Next;
    m_FreeBlock->Next->Prev = m_FreeBlock->Prev;
    m_FreeBlock = m_FreeBlock->Next;
}

return allocated;

}
```

I already checked if the SearchByPolicy function returns a valid pointer and it does return a valid pointer if it can find a bigger block of memory then the request.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of pointer arithmetic:

```
FooterBlock* footer = (FooterBlock*)((header + Size - m_fsize));
```

means

```
FooterBlock* footer = (FooterBlock*)((uint_ptr)header + (sizeof(HeaderBlock) * Size) - (sizeof(HeaderBlock) * m_fsize));
```

you most likely wanted:

```
uint_ptr ofs = (uint_ptr)header;
FooterBlock* footer = (FooterBlock*)((ofs + Size - m_fsize));
```

you can find `uint_ptr` in `stdint.h` or `UINT_PTR` in `windows.h`

---

**Update:**

As per the question in the comment

```
IMemoryManager* memorymanager = new MemoryManager(1000000); 
Logger* logger = (Logger*)memorymanager->Allocate(sizeof(Logger)); 
logger->WriteToBuffer(log, "HOI");
```

this will fail because the constructor for `Logger` will not be called, there are a few ways to fix this:

- call a construction method, not very nice though
- use placement new:

(lists break code formatting unfortunately, so I have to insert this here...)

```
IMemoryManager* memorymanager = new MemoryManager(1000000); 
Logger* logger = new (memorymanager->Allocate(sizeof(Logger))) (); 
logger->WriteToBuffer(log, "HOI");
```

- overload the `::new` and `::delete` operators at a global scope (very bad)
- create a inheritable object to overload `new` and `delete`:

This requires that the memory manager be available at that point (or passed as a param):

```
class PoolObject
{
    void* operator new (std::size_t n)
    {
        return memorymanager->Allocate(n);
    }

    void operator delete (void* p)
    {
        memorymanager->Free(p);
    }
}

class Logger : PoolObject
{
}

Logger* logger = new Logger();
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT it worked like a charm~!

Just one more problem:

let's say I have a pointer to my memory manager and a logger:

    IMemoryManager* memorymanager = new MemoryManager(1000000);
    Logger* logger = (Logger*)memorymanager>Allocate(sizeof(Logger));

    logger->WriteToBuffer(log, "HOI");

What's wrong with this then?

Again thank you very much, if you could answer this last question I won't ask you anything again:P You get a vote up from me!

Comment: @ChristianVeenman: you are allocating an object without initializing it (the constructor won't be called). see my update question.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! You really are great at explaining!

Do you think it would be a good idea to create a constructor and use placement new in the constructor to initialize it in the allocated memory? I accepted your answer by the way!

Comment: @ChristianVeenman: I'm not sure what you mean by that, the constructor for `Logger` won't be called without placement new, in which case it doesn't matter, as you can just do everything in the constructor